# Limit on number of Paypal Billing Agreements

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am implementing Paypal express checkout (using paypal rest sdk for php )in one of my projects for recurring billing (for subscription), every thing is working fine for the initial requests (about 10 checkouts) after that I start to get Error 400 for few days and then everything starts working again.

I just wanted to confirm if there is any sort of limit on creating billing agreement in sandbox environment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, the reason I was getting error 400 after some times was because I was setting a static time while creating billing agreement.

```
 $agreement = new Agreement();
 $agreement->setName('My Billing Agreement')
            ->setDescription('Subscription to My Billing Agreement')
            ->setStartDate(date('Y-m-d').'T9:45:04Z');
```

The reason this snippet was resulting in error is because the start date/time of the billing agreement can only be a future time. 
All I needed to do was replace

```
setStartDate(date('Y-m-d').'T9:45:04Z')
```

with

```
setStartDate(date("c", time() + 1800))
```

and everything started working as expected. Hope this helps some one.